# Using @Id for multiple fields in same class

Tags: hibernate

I am a newbie to Hibernate and have to support an existing application that uses Hibernate
    It is a pure reporting application - no insert / update / delete - only selects

I can see existing POJO objects which have the @Id annotation used in more than one field in the same class

My understanding was that for a composite primary key - you need to use @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId

However this is not defined in my class and the strange thing is code compiles and runs just fine

Here is an example of my code :

```
package com.xyz.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity(name="com.xyz.vo.Emp")
@Table(name = "TEmployee")
public class Emp implements Serializable    {
private java.lang.Integer  empId;
@Id 
@Column(name = "EMP_ID")   
public java.lang.Integer  getEmpId(){   
    return this.empId;
}

public  void  setEmpId(java.lang.Integer empId){    
    this.empId=empId;
}

private java.lang.Integer  empAge;
@Id 
@Column(name = "EMP_AGE")   
public java.lang.Integer  getEmpAge(){  
    return this.empAge;
}

    public  void  setEmpAge(java.lang.Integer empAge){  
    this.empAge=empAge;
}

    private String empName;
    @Column(name = "EMP_NAME")   
public String  getEmpName(){    
    return this.empName;
}

    public  void  setEmpName(String empName){   
    this.empName=empName;
}
```

and many more fields in the pojo - which do not have the @Id defined

NOTE - here two fields have the @Id annotation

I am confused why this compiles and works ?
Thanks
akila

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the Hibernate docs, Hibernate seems to allow this but it is not however JPA compliant.

> 5.1.2.1.2. Multiple id properties without identifier type
>
> Another, arguably more natural, approach is to place @Id on multiple
>   properties of your entity. This approach is only supported by
>   Hibernate (not JPA compliant) but does not require an extra embeddable
>   component.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4819

For a JPA compliant solution you would have to specify an additional @IDClass for this set-up (or use an EmbeddedId):

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id