# What are differences in many to many mapping approach

Tags: spring, orm, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

I want many to many relation mapping with explicit join table.

My java spring project is providing REST api in HAL format and now it has only two types of classed:

- entities defined and
- "empty" interfaces for repositories (annotated by @RepositoryRestResource).

Sidenote, dependencies are circa these:

```
spring-boot-starter-parent
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring-boot-starter-data-rest
spring-data-rest-hal-browser
postgresql / h2
spring-boot-starter-hateoas
```

Relations between tables (I mean _links of rest resources. have a look at [sample hal+json](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) document and look for `ea:basket` for example.) are working as expected and it is working "for free", because of magic powder from spring auto-configuration and other magic included.

I am struggling now when adding new many to many dependency.

I have entities A, B and Tag. I want to have any number of Tag entities to be associated with A an B entities. I have no need to have any list/set in A and B entities (I will use jooq if I need anything more than crud).

**First problem/question:**

I see at least three approaches to model many to many relation with explicit join table (to be able to model my association needs) and I do not know differences. **What are differences of these approaches?**:

1. use embeddable composite key in join table as Vlad suggest? https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/
2. use @IdClass approach as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588400/11152683
3. use multiple @Id in join table as shown here: https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-extra-columns-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-hsql/

**Second question:**
What approach is needed in my case to easily model associations and make magic powder do its work when providing HAL format in crud repositories. I mean that links of relations will be generated automagically.

Comment: 3 is just an alternative to 2 and is supported by Hibernate but is not part of the JPA specification. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813372/using-id-for-multiple-fields-in-same-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make many2many association work nicely with spring data rest things and provide HAL representation with correct things, you have first know a bit of JPA/Hibernate. There are two approaches (1 and 2 from question, as third is only shortcut for second one and working in Hibernate only.).

Both approaches are shown in proof of concept [repository in tags branch](https://github.com/luvarqpp/poc-springHalRelations/tree/feature/tags). I use given repository to test various set-ups of project.

**Approach 1, EmbeddedId**. It does use hackish thing in FixConfig class in BackendIdConverter bean, where it uses bookRepository to get Book entity when it parses request id from url onto embedable id class.

**Approach 2, IdClass**. It is using plain Integers int its IdClass and does seem to be correct solution.

I think that first approach can be modified to work similarly as second, but I am not able to do it for now.

I would mark as solution any answer providing some insight for "why" it is like this.