# EntityNotfoundException - Hibernate & Springboot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am using Springboot with hibernate and the database in MS SQL. I have below two Entity classes PS and CFO. CFO has two primary keys - CFO_ID & LAST_UPDATE_DTS and both of them are referenced as foreign keys in CFO table. And when I try to fetch PS and access cfo using getter method, am getting EntityNotFound Exception even though data exists in DB.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PS")
@Data
@IdClass(PlanSponsorId.class)
public class PS implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1685251075449473233L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PS_ID", columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
    private Integer ps_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATE_DTS", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private Date lastUpateTimestamp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "CFO_ID",referencedColumnName="CFO_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "CFO_LAST_UPDATE_DTS",referencedColumnName="LAST_UPDATE_DTS") })
    private CFO cfo;

//other fields
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PlanSponsorId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2224235254147911360L;
    private Date lastUpateTimestamp;
    private Integer ps_id;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CFO")
@Data
@IdClass(value = CFOModelId.class)
public class CFO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1082267441376710907L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CFO_ID", columnDefinition = "CHAR(3)")
    private String cfoIdentifier;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATE_DTS", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private Date lastUpateTimestamp;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cfo")
    private List<PS> ps;

//other fields
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CFOModelId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -325079478600059751L;
    private String cfoIdentifier;
    private Date lastUpateTimestamp;
}

javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.abc.CFO with id CFOModelId(cfoIdentifier=1  , lastUpateTimestamp=2019-12-30 01:36:08.773)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45)
```

When I keep only one as primary key - either CFO_ID or LAST_UPDATE_DTS and remove Idclass altogether, it works perfectly fine. This make me think that something is wrong with idclass but I couldn't find any. Can someone pls help?

Answer (score -1):

According to the Hibernate docs, Hibernate seems to allow this but it is not however JPA compliant.

```
5.1.2.1.2. Multiple id properties without identifier type

Another, arguably more natural, approach is to place @Id on multiple properties of your entity. This approach is only supported by Hibernate (not JPA compliant) but does not require an extra embeddable component.
```

For a JPA compliant solution you would have to specify an additional @IDClass for this set-up (or use an EmbeddedId):

ref:[Using @Id for multiple fields in same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813372/using-id-for-multiple-fields-in-same-class)

Example:

```
@Entity 
@IdClass(ProjectId.class)
public class Project {
@Id int departmentId;
@Id long projectId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sushil. I already tried embeddedid as well but it didn't work out. For now, i removed the column definition from column annotation on Last_update_dts and that is working without issues. But am not sure whether it is the right solution.